# Is HTML5 stable enough ?

Tags: html

I was thinking about learning HTML5 (in fact, I've leant a bit of CANVAS object).

But my question is if it would be reasonable to learn it: is it already fully standard?, or is it going to change?

Thanks.

Comment: A question about a certain behavior in HTML5 is fine, but asking for opinions in it's stability results in an election.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 (or just HTML) will never be "stable". The official specification documents what browsers are doing, and it'll always be behind what different browsers are capable of doing. Instead you should consider each piece/feature on its own: is it supported in the browsers you need it in, and if not, can you degrade to a different experience for users browsing from non-compatible browsers?

A really good resource to have in your toolbox is http://html5doctor.com/. They have detailed information that is updated frequently on most of the features grouped together under the HTML5 label.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is a collection of thousands of features. Some of them are stable, some of them are not.

But you really only need to worry about browser-support. If a feature is implemented in all modern browsers, then it is safe regardless of whether it's a HTML5 feature or not.

So it is reasonable to learn about those HTML5 features that are already implemented in the browsers. You can check out which those features are here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as much or as little as you wish since it's backwards compatible with v4.01.